# python audio doesn't play

Tags: python, qt, audio, pyside, phonon

When I type the following code in Python, the `song.mp3` doesn't play. Why??

```
output = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.MusicCategory) 
m_media = Phonon.MediaObject() 
Phonon.createPath(m_media, output) 
m_media.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource("files/song.mp3")) 
m_media.play()
```

Comment: yes, except the imports. The code runs without error but song doesn'y play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need QApplication or QCoreApplication instance and you have to launch event loop with exec() member after m_media.play(). Phonon::MediaObject::play is asynchronous.

C++ example

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
// phonon initialization, and play
app.exec()
```